# The CSharpPackage package did load correctly in VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

The 'CSharpPackage' package did not load correctly.

Whenever i open any project in VS2015. this error occurs, and i am unable to Run any project or Create a new Project... Please any help me to resolve this problem.

Additional info;

VS2015 Enterprise.

Win10 Profesional.

Due to many packages's issue i repaired VS, after repair only this error occurs. remaining issues are resolved.

Comment: what error occurred?

Comment: The 'CSharpPackage' package did not load correctly.

Comment: Did you try to install uninstall your software?

Comment: No. Its just repaired. please tell me if there is any solution without clean re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using MVC need t install your project:

Go to tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console > [MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/)

Comment: Or install uninstall your software then install MVC to make it refresh.

Comment: This issue exist with MVC, But i have tried to open simple asp.net project. the problem is same with all Projects.

Comment: install uninstall mean?. i think u mean uninstall VS and then re-install?

Comment: Yeah that's what i mean